# Prepending information in a text file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access a simple text file using StreamWriter. I need it to check each line in a text file and and prepend zeros to the beginning of the line until that line is equal to a length of 31.
My code compiles correctly, but after it executes it does nothing to the actual file in question. What am I doing wrong?

```
StreamReader Editor = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New folder\\DHStest.txt", true);
       string reader = Editor.ReadToEnd();


using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter("DHStest.txt"))
{
    string output = reader.PadLeft(31, '0');

    Writer.Write(output);
    Writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: I imagine there's a file in your project's bin folder called "DHStest.txt".

Comment: Well, this block is a smaller part of a larger program I have been working on. It creates the 'DHStest' file and adds information from my dataset to the file in two seperate lines. Now my issue is I can't actually get it modify the information as I need to once its been appended to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first problem is you are writing to a different file than you're reading from.

your second problem is you're not reading the file in line by line, like you want.

You want:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\DHStest.txt";

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines.Select(x => x.PadLeft(31, '0')));
```

read all the lines, then write them back out with the padding.

Comment: Huh, thats a great deal simpler than what I was trying to do. Most excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but why not:

```
File.WriteAllLines("myFile.txt", 
    File.ReadLines("myFile.txt").Select(s => s.PadLeft(31, '0')).ToArray());
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it a line at a time, you need to read the individual lines.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line.PadLeft(31, '0'));
    }
}
```

The reason you're not seeing the modified file is that you're not opening it with the full path. That is, you have:

```
using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter("DHStest.txt"))
```

Which is going to open the file in the current working directory -- probably the directory that contains the executable.

Comment: Well, I attempted to implement your code but I ran into some trouble. Its not accepting

    writer.WriteLine(line.PadLeft(31, '0'));

as valid.